# Require Azure authentication for Internal user and external user in same application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, acs

I have a requirement to provide SSO authentication using Azure ACS for External User and Internal User(Azure AD) for single application. Can any one please let me know is it possible to implement it.
How user can be identified as external or internal user.

Comment: I'm sorry but how is ACS connected to authentication?

Comment: Requirement is to use Azure to authenticate Internal and external user for same application. please let me know how can we achieve this. Any  link which explain this mixed mode will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

> > Requirement is to use Azure to authenticate Internal and external user for same application

Yes , you could achieve that . For external User , you could add the identity provider at the ACS config portal :
[image]

For AAD account , you could refer to this article : [Provisioning a Windows Azure Active Directory Tenant as an Identity Provider in an ACS Namespace](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2012/11/07/PROVISIONING-A-DIRECTORY-TENANT-AS-AN-IDENTITY-PROVIDER-IN-AN-ACS-NAMESPACE/).

But notice ,  Identity & Access tools only available in vs2012, in vs2013/vs2015 , you could create a MVC app and  Choose Organizational Accounts and select On-Premises as option , Please check detail steps from [here](http://blog.bekijkhet.com/2014/05/how-to-authenticate-mvc5-web-users-with.html).

> > How user can be identified as external or internal user.

You could check the identity provider claim value (http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider), it represents the identity provider , for Microsoft account it will be :
[image] ,for azure ad account , it will like: https://sts.windows.net/tenantID/
[image]

Please let me know if it helps.